# Why won't my Serverless Framework VSCode debug configuration execute?

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, vscode-debugger

I am using Serverless Framework to create a node API backend for my web app. VSCode is my IDE, running on Windows 11.

The VSCODE Run and Debug widget fails immediately with an error that I cannot comprehend or fix.

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "run SLS",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/api/fq-transcribe/node_modules/.bin/sls",
      "args": ["invoke", "local", "-f", "fqTranscribe", "-p", "./test-events/event.json"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\david\build\frequency\api\fq-transcribe\node_modules\.bin\sls:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at compileFunction (vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:22:47)
vm:360
Process exited with code 1
```

Here is the SLS file:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  exec "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../serverless/bin/serverless.js" "$@"
else 
  exec node  "$basedir/../serverless/bin/serverless.js" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: do you actually want to debug this program? Or do you just want to run it? If you just want to run it, use [a task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) instead of a launch config.

Comment: [`sls`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sls) might have a bug, (or maybe it just doesn't support Windows). Based on the error, something seems to be expecting to run in a Bash-like shell in a UNIX environment. For example `dirname` is not the name of a cmdlet, function, or operable program in Windows. But looking at [the source code, there are no instances of usage of `dirname` in the source](https://github.com/brunosimon/sls/search?q=dirname), and it doesn't use any dependencies, so I'm not sure how this is happening.

Comment: `sls` in the bin folder might be a wrapper script to run a node program. What do you see if you open `.../bin/sls` as a text file?

Comment: Hi User -- thanks for your input.  "sls" is a command to start Serverless Framework, not the Brunosimon github you found.    I do want to debug, not just run.  Adding the SLS file to the main post above.

Comment: [bin programs for npm packages are usually scripts wrapping a command to run nodejs to run a JS program](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin). If you want to debug it, I believe you need to pass the JS program's entrypoint script to your launch config and not that npm-generated wrapper script. What happens if you instead pass the path to `.../serverless/bin/serverless.js` in your launch.json's `program` field?

Comment: Good suggestion, that seems better, except unfortunately I just get a "Process exited with code 1" with zero information, no other console or debug messages whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from a colleague, I got this working. I can now do breakpoint debugging on Serverless Offline and with Serverless Invoke Local on Windows. We also know how to do Mac and Linux, I'll share that as well.

Here is the `launch.json` file. The first config is for Serverless Offline, the second config is for Invoke Local. You may have to update the cwd to reach the directory with your serverless.yml file.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Debug Serverless Offline",
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "skipFiles": [
              "<node_internals>/**"
          ],
          "args": [
              "run",
              "debug"
          ],
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "runtimeExecutable": "npm"
      },
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Serverless Invoker",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "args": [
            "run",
            "invoker"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm"
    }
  ]
}
```

Add this to your package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless offline -s dev --reloadHandler",
    "invoker": "node --inspect node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless invoke local -f YourFunctionNameHere"

  },
```

For Mac/Linux, it's exactly the same except one thing:
In your package.json: runtimeExecutable must be the full path to your npm. Use `which npm` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to [@dcyprianrw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18638021/dcyprianrw), make sure the `outDir` of your tsconfig matches the `outDir` used by `serverless-plugin-typescript`. Looks like the vscode debugger will search for sourcemaps in the `outDir` of your tsconfig.json (even if you point it in the right direction with `outFiles` in `launch.json`)

From the [serverless-plugin-typescript docs](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-typescript):

```
// The default tsconfig.json file used by the plugin looks like this: 
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

If you want to use a custom tsconfig, you'll have to specify the path in your serverless-local.yml:

```
custom:
  serverlessPluginTypescript:
    tsConfigFileLocation: './tsconfig.build.json'
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. I spent hours tweaking endless configuration and couldn't get this to work - and this is exactly what I needed.